# Trying to close a modal popup using findelement

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Webdriver with C#

I'm trying to close a modal pop-up using findelement.  Not sure which findelement to use for this to close the modal.

//HTML

```
    <div id="simplemodal-container" class="simplemodal-container" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 297px; padding: 0px; width: 984px; position: fixed; z-index: 1002; left: 138.5px; top: 75.5px;">
        <a class="modalCloseImg simplemodal-close" title="Close"></a>
        <div class="simplemodal-wrap" tabindex="-1" style="height: 100%; outline: 0px none; width: 100%; overflow: visible;">
            <div id="simplemodal-data" class="simplemodal-data" style="">
                <div class="modal_info tariff_T010129">
                    <img class="table_image" width="974" height="287" longdesc="http://www.three.ie/products_services/priceplans/billpay/index.html" alt="Flexifix tariff info" src="https://www.three.ie/imgs/shop/tariff_info/flexifix-tariff-table.jpg" style="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS for X button

```
        #simplemodal-container a.modalCloseImg {
        background: url("../Content/Images/x.png") no-repeat; top: -15px; width: 25px; height: 29px; right: -18px; display: inline; position: absolute; z-index: 3200; cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way, since you've already found the relevant `CSS` for this element would to use that.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.modalCloseImg")).click();
```

(That's in `Java` but I'm sure you'll be able to modify for `C#`.)